# onClick Removing data from components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I have two components. In Component 1 there is an img. In component 2 there is a button. I need when i press the button img disappears and also button disappears.

```
const Icons=()=> {
  return (
        <div className="_icons">
             <div className="icons__Top">
             <img src="./icons/-48.png" alt="Twitter"/>
                  <figcaption>Whatever</figcaption>
             </div>
        </div>

const Button= () => {
    return (
        <div className="button">
            <Button variant="outlined" className="button__rightpage" >REMOVE</Button>
            <caption className="text" ></caption>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Are these 2 components share a common parent ?

Comment: You seem to be mixing HTML and Javascript - can you show where you call these functions and tell us anything you have tried? Using your browsers dev tools and looking at errors in the console would help you remove syntax error before submitting code here.

Comment: @Anup they have seperate parent component

Comment: @AHaworth It's React and the html is actually JSX. The functions are React components

Comment: @charlietfl thanks I'd missed that

Answer (score -1):

There can be more than one solution,
1)I think you need to have one parent component for both components and make one state in parent component and then pass it in icon component and give it to img and default make it to false and then from button component change that state to true.

2)without parent component -> You can also use context api to change value directly from button component and hide img.

Comment: they have seperate parent component

Comment: Thank you for giving me low vote for helping you. I have also given you the solution for not having parent component.